# Errors when running webpack for Angular 5 server-side rendering

Tags: angular, firebase, webpack, angular5, angular-universal

I'm attempting to integrate server-side rendering into my Angular 5 website. I've been using this guide: https://www.genuitec.com/angular-5-firebase-angular-universal/ The guide mirrors Angular's own guide very closely. My implementation differs only where absolutely necessary.

As a part of the implementation, it recommends adding the following scripts to your **package.json** file:

```
    "build:universal": "npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server",
    "serve:universal": "node dist/server.js",
    "build:client-and-server-bundles": "ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false",
    "webpack:server": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
```

However, when I run `npm run build:universal`, I getting the follow result:

```
> commonwealthlinen@0.0.0 build:universal /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1
> npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server


> commonwealthlinen@0.0.0 build:client-and-server-bundles /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1
> ng build --prod && ng build --prod --app 1 --output-hashing=false

Date: 2018-02-22T14:07:04.059Z
Hash: cf295e0d6c63da436ecd
Time: 50320ms
chunk {0} main.ef135b8d11eba44c66eb.bundle.js (main) 892 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {1} polyfills.ec6ea079491a34c09d8d.bundle.js (polyfills) 59.1 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} styles.d41d8cd98f00b204e980.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} inline.19a4c06712152fdead2c.bundle.js (inline) 1.45 kB [entry] [rendered]
Date: 2018-02-22T14:07:19.302Z
Hash: de693eccb257cfc2c294
Time: 12671ms
chunk {0} main.bundle.js (main) 188 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.bundle.css (styles) 0 bytes [entry] [rendered]

> commonwealthlinen@0.0.0 webpack:server /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1
> webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors

Hash: 3ac91d65aa5c64d8b525
Version: webpack 3.11.0
Time: 28507ms
    Asset     Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
server.js  6.51 MB       0  [emitted]  [big]  server
 [124] ./src lazy 160 bytes {0} [built]
 [229] ./server.ts 1.79 kB {0} [built]
 [296] ./src 160 bytes {0} [built]
 [302] (webpack)/buildin/module.js 517 bytes {0} [built]
 [315] ./dist/server/main.bundle.js 188 kB {0} [built]
 [405] (webpack)/buildin/harmony-module.js 596 bytes {0} [built]
    + 440 hidden modules

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts(249,9)
      TS2420: Class 'ZoneAwarePromise<R>' incorrectly implements interface 'Promise<R>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'ZoneAwarePromise<R>'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts(255,7)
      TS2322: Type 'ZoneAwarePromise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<R>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'ZoneAwarePromise<any>'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts(259,7)
      TS2322: Type 'ZoneAwarePromise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<U>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'ZoneAwarePromise<any>'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts(310,7)
      TS2322: Type 'ZoneAwarePromise<R>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<R>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'ZoneAwarePromise<R>'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/common/promise.ts(333,13)
      TS2322: Type 'ZoneAwarePromise<TResult1 | TResult2>' is not assignable to type 'Promise<TResult1 | TResult2>'.
  Property '[Symbol.toStringTag]' is missing in type 'ZoneAwarePromise<TResult1 | TResult2>'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts(136,11)
      TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Zone'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts(493,6)
      TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'HasTaskState'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts(500,6)
      TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TaskType'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts(505,6)
      TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'TaskState'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/zone.js/lib/zone.ts(628,7)
      TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable 'Zone'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts(17,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts(18,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'sinon'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(82,7)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'before'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(86,7)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'after'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/deepCopy.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/deepCopy.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/base64.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/firebase/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/base64.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts(17,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts(18,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'sinon'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(82,7)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'before'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(86,7)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'after'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/deepCopy.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/deepCopy.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/base64.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/base64.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/src/polyfills/promise.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/polyfill/src/polyfills/promise.ts(17,7)
      TS2451: Cannot redeclare block-scoped variable '__global'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts(17,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/subscribe.test.ts(18,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'sinon'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(82,7)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'before'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/errors.test.ts(86,7)
      TS2304: Cannot find name 'after'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/deepCopy.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/deepCopy.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/base64.test.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/messaging/node_modules/@firebase/util/test/base64.test.ts(16,24)
      TS2307: Cannot find module 'chai'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/index.node.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/index.node.ts(19,27)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './src/api/database'.

ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/index.node.ts
[tsl] ERROR in /Users/kwlester/Documents/JurassicRevenge/commonwealthlinen1/functions/node_modules/@firebase/firestore/index.node.ts(20,38)
      TS2307: Cannot find module './src/platform/config'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! commonwealthlinen@0.0.0 webpack:server: `webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the commonwealthlinen@0.0.0 webpack:server script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kwlester/.npm/_logs/2018-02-22T14_07_48_823Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! commonwealthlinen@0.0.0 build:universal: `npm run build:client-and-server-bundles && npm run webpack:server`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the commonwealthlinen@0.0.0 build:universal script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/kwlester/.npm/_logs/2018-02-22T14_07_48_858Z-debug.log
```

From what I can tell, initializing firebase functions is causing the issue. I've been able to implement server-side rendering in a vanilla Angular 5 install, however, as soon as I firebase init functions, I starts throwing errors.

If I delete the **node_modules** directory inside of the **functions** directory, the errors go away. Why are these errors being thrown, and how can I satisfy them?

**EDIT:**

Here's the **tsconfig.server.json** that I'm using. It's a direct copy from Angular's website:

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "types": []
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
  }
}
```

Comment: did you make the tsconfig.server.json file? Can you post it?

Comment: @CapitanFindus I posted it above. It's exactly the same as the tsconfig example on Angular's website and the tutorial posted above.

Comment: @CapitanFindus I found that I was able to implement SSR in a vanilla Angular 5 instance. However, as soon as I init firebase functions, it starts throwing those errors.

Comment: is building the normal app (not the `platform: server` version) working?